# JQuery while-loop becomes unresponsive with inArray comparison to optimise array content

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, match

I have a function that uses a random process and tests for overlap in an array.

Something like this:

It takes an array of colours and picks two of them randomly and puts them into a new array.
Then it tests whether there is overlap in this new array of two colours `new_array` (i.e. whether we do not have two different colours). This test sums the returned indices of `inArray()` so that it returns a `0` if there is no overlap and `-1` if there is.

```
function test_overlap() {
  window.overlap_output = [];
  var all_colours = ["red", "red", "black", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"];
  var random_index1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  var random_index2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  var new_array = [all_colours[random_index1], all_colours[random_index2]];
  $.each(new_array, function(i, val) {
    var overlap_test = $.inArray(val, new_array);
    overlap_output.push(overlap_test - i);
  });
  $.each(overlap_output, function() {
    checksum += this;
  });
}
```

This works as I want it to. However, I now want to automise this as an optimisation in the sense that it runs this function as long as possible until the `checksum` value is `0`. In other words, until I have an array of two different colours.

I wanted to do this with `while` in a new function:

```
function optimise_colours() {
  window.checksum = -1;
  while (checksum !== 0){
    test_overlap();
  }
}
```

Here, I declare `checksum` to be used in the `while` loop and then want to run it while the result is not the desired `0`.

However, if I run `optimise_colours()` - unless it gets a "perfect" array initially - the browser gets trouble as it takes too long and returns "unresponsive script".

My question is this: is there a way to fix my problem and did I make a mistake in my code logic, or is this not doable in JavaScript/JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar problem: my mistake was in my code logic as I suspected.

In my while loop, the `checksum` of the `test_overlap()` function will become more negative with each run. I had to insert a line where I reset the `checksum` value to `0` before summing the `inArray()` indices again:

```
function test_overlap() {
  window.overlap_output = [];
  var all_colours = ["red", "red", "black", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red", "red"];
  var random_index1 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  var random_index2 = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  var new_array = [all_colours[random_index1], all_colours[random_index2]];
  $.each(new_array, function(i, val) {
    var overlap_test = $.inArray(val, new_array);
    overlap_output.push(overlap_test - i);
  });
#here I need to reset the checksum value to zero
  checksum = 0;
  $.each(overlap_output, function() {
    checksum += this;
  });
}
```

Without resetting that value, this happened: it runs `test_overlap()` and returns a negative `checksum` as there is overlap. Then the checksum value decreases from `-1` to `-2`. This is not the condition that should be met, so stay in the `while` loop and run again:

**Now here was the problem:** no matter the outcome of the second run of `test_overlap()`, the checksum value it received initially was `-2` and even if the returned result for this run was `0` (i.e. no overlap), the value could not possibly have changed to `0`.

Resetting this before each `checksum` calculation fixes this.

Note that the initial value of `checksum` in `optimise_colours()` is `-1` in order to let the while loop run at least once.

Hope this helps if someone has a similar problem.